# Modify Json file in a server usin C#

Tags: c#, json

I have this JSon file:

```
{
"fruits": [
{
   "id":"01",
   "name": "orange"
},
{
   "id":"02",
   "name": "banana"
}]
}
```

This file is in a server (http://localhost/fruits.json)

I want to develop a windows application in order to be able to add to this json file as many fruits as I want, I am able to get the JSon string from the server using JSon.net, but I am unable to change the JSon file content from the c# application.

I was wondering if it is possible to do it and how it could be acomplish.

Comment: You just want to add a fruit to fruits collection or you wanna modify the collection and POST data back to server?

Comment: Post some C# code from your app.

Comment: You should be parsing this to a strongly-typed object, modifying the C# object and re-serializing to send to the client.  You should NEVER modify a JSON string directly in the C# layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to deserialize the JSON string into a strongly typed object (as @David said in the comments) and then modify it. If you wanna send data back to the server you should serialize your `object` back to JSON and POST it back to server.
Here is a sample for deserializing your JSON string:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string id;
    public string name;
}

public class FruitCollection
{
    public List<Fruit> fruits;
}

...

string jsonString = "Your JSON string goes here";
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(FruitCollection));
FruitCollection fruitCollection = null;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)))
{
    fruitCollection = (FruitCollection)ser.ReadObject(ms);
}
```

Now that you have the `fruitCollection` object which contains you actual collection, you can add some fruits to it.